# User management and access frameworks

Tags: php, acl, membership

I'm looking to add an image upload and comment area to an already existing site. Not wanting to reinvent the wheel I'm wondering if there are any "drop in" ways to handle user management and security.

I've begun looking at frameworks like Codeigniter, but as far as I can see they need to be installed in the root of the system and as I said, the rest of the site is already there.

I also noticed that Symfony has a standalone security suite for PHP but I didn't see a user management component.

I guess going further down the DRY "reinvent the wheel"...is there any already existing open source framework that has members pages where they can upload images. I currently work in php, but I'm open to suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: They do not need to be installed at the root of the system at all. That's the whole point of them using mod_rewrite and htaccess extensively. You can put them anywhere, and only use the code for certain urls through a combination of clever htaccess file (assuming you are on httpd)

Comment: Ok, so then you use the equivalent to htaccess files, or just make the modifications in your main config file. All I am saying is that you could absolutely use one of those MVC frameworks, without having it control your entire site. I do not know about any software that does exactly what you want off the top of my head. I would say google is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is the ability to upload images and have users comment, then why not incorporate the functionality of an existing image gallery into your application? Most of those will already include user management. This website lists some of the more common galleries: http://www.design3edge.com/2010/08/26/best-free-and-open-source-php-image-galleries/. There is bound to be one you like in that list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, there's quite a few gallery softwares  that I was unaware of before. Sadly they all suffer from the old "do most of the things I want but not all" syndrome. :-) I'll have to check with their developers if any of them are close to adding what I need or see if their various plugins will enable the features I need. If nothing else I can go back to my drop-in ACL and Auth search and use the other galleries as inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

Well, It seems you need something like [cms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system),

and you are asking this from framework(which cms does). I will suggest you to go with cms, For php there lots of cms:

- [Druapl](http://drupal.org)
- [Joomla](http://joomla.org)

So, you do not write any code for your requirement, just drop modules into folder, and turn on them.

If you really want framework, then I would suggest you go with module based framework like [yii](http://yiiframework.com). I has tons of modules, that you can include and use it, But they are not ultimate as cms's modules. In yii it is called [exnetnsion](http://www.yiiframework.com/extensions/)
here is some extensions:

- [yii-user-management](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-user-management/)
- [Comments](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/comments-module)

If I were you I would go with cms's. For this kind of DRY things, They are the best and built in for this purpose.